# Modulus.io and Socket.io problems

Tags: node.js, socket.io, modulus.io

I am making a socket.io app, it is working perfectly locally, until i try to put it on Modulus.io, Then I can't connect to my app, it isn't generating an error though... this is some relevant code:
(Server)

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(Number(process.env.PORT) || 8080)
io.set('log level', 5);
io.set("origins = *");
```

It says **info - socket.io started** and that's it. When I try to connect, socket.on("error") fires with ETIMEOUT

Comment: I guess the client is connecting to a different host and/or port than the server listens at. Check if you have set the correct host and port parameters on the client side. If you have not declared them, socket.io will use default values. They might work locally, but not on your webhost.

Comment: @1nsane I have console.log'd the uri, got this: `ws://url.of-webhost.net:8080` Any ideas

Comment: The client should connect to port 80. ws://url.of-webhost.net. Modulus redirects public traffic on port 80 to traffic internally to your app on port 8080.